# How to get my Android project from one computer to the other?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a laptop that I'm using to work on my app in Eclipse. I share the computer so it's not always available. How can I get the entire Android project from my laptop's Eclipse to the Eclipse on my PC? I don't want to email each individual file to myself and open it on the PC, either.

Comment: Or just copy the whole project folder from one eclipse workspace to the other.

Comment: And remember to copy your debug.keystore (Default location is %USERPROFILE%/.android/debug.keystore ). If you using different keys you can't overwrite an old test build on a real device without first uninstall it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your project's source code to be open on the public, you can use `github` or `Google code` or something similar. Then you should install a plugin to Eclipse in order to be able to synchronize easy your code.

At my early steps, I was using `Dropbox` for project synching. It was good for projects that only one person writes to them. If many people participate, then this solution is a mess.

Also you can set up your own sych server, if you have a pc that is online 24/7 or when you need it. I tried to set up a `Gitorious` but I haven't managed to get it running 100%. So, for now I have an `SVN` server, and using the Eclipse plugin for SVN synching, I have everywhere I want my eclipse projects. To setup an SVN synch server is very easy and will not take more than a few hours(minutes??).

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to copy your project from one computer to another, on the first one choose in eclipse: File->Export...->General->Archive file, then select project(s) to export, choose archive name and format and save it. Copy archive file to second PC. In the second eclipse choose: File->Import...->General->Existing Projects into Workspace->Select archive file. Select your archive, select project(s) to import. Voila!

Comment: will this export the keystores as well?

Comment: Sorry, can't check because don't use eclipse anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surrounded by computers all day long, but I don't have access to install anything on them.  My solution is that I made a Lubuntu Live USB drive that I then installed Eclipse and the Android dvelopment tools on.  Luckily the BIOS is not locked on any of the computers so I boot the closest computer up using my USB drive as the OS and everything is exactly as I left it no matter which computer I'm at.  When I am at home and I want to code I boot my desktop or laptop up using that drive as well.